# Sort/Order string output Apache Impala SQL query

Tags: sql, impala

Hello I have a string output in my query and I want to sort by this column. The Column contains only strings but two of them are date strings and one is characters only.

I want to sort/order by the date strings first and the character string should be at last position.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1 ORDER BY column1;
```

column1 contains following data as string:

```
ROW1: Older
ROW2: 19.03.2023
ROW3: 20.03.2023
```

I want the output as follows:

```
Column1        column2        column3
20.03.2023     some value     some value
19.03.2023     some value     some value
Older          some value     some value
```

How to do that, a simple ORDER BY is not working correctly.
Thanks

Comment: what kind of sorting you want - ascending? descending ? alphabetical ?date sort ?

Comment: @KoushikRoy I have written the output that I want to have. Today should be first row, yesterday should be second row and Older should be last. I edit the output in my question

Comment: If you want a string to be ordered by date, you need it to be `YYYY-MM-DD`. Otherwise, `01-02-2023` is naturally going to come before `02-01-2023`

Comment: Are there any other strings that can appear, such as `'Newer'`? Or is `'Older'` the ***only*** non-date string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data into yyyy,mm,dd, actual value, it should work. Pls check it out.

```
order by split_part(column1,'.',3),  split_part(column1,'.',2),  split_part(column1,'.',1), column1
```

Comment: What about the `'Older'` row?

Comment: thank you this is working perfectly for me if I add DESC to each split_part.

Comment: `older` will go to bottom because all split() will generate null.